# simple probability/proportion question

Tags: probability, proportion

Say among 100 people who are 65+ years old and randomly selected from the population, 10 have dementia.

Can I say a 65+ year old person will have dementia with 0.1 chance ?

Thx

Comment: It depends.  Where is probability involved?  What does it mean to say "can have" a disease?  How are the 100 people selected?  To see this is not mere nit-picking, suppose 100 people present as patients to a physician, who determines 10 of them show traits leading to sickle cell disease.  Would it make sense to tell the other 90 that they each have a 0.1 chance of having sickle cell disease?  Of course not.  That's why you must be more specific.

Comment: I rephrased my question. Can the statement be valid now? For your sickle cell problem. why cannot we tell the other 90 of the 100 patients have 0.1 chance of having the disease? because they do not show symptoms of sickle cell disease?

Comment: I am a little troubled by your change of tense: the proportion of people in a sample who *currently* have dementia may be very different from the proportion in the population who *will* have dementia.  You might be realizing that phrasing things in terms of chances or probability can be delicate and risks misunderstanding.  Your initial sentence is much clearer than the second one.  Why not relate your information exactly as you have in the first sentence, so that your listener will know what you know?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with population inference vs individual inference?

Comment: That might be part of it, but the aspect that caught my attention was the apparent change in the definition of what the population is.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I say a 65+ year old person will have dementia with 0.1 chance?

It depends. First, "randomly sampled from the population" could mean different things. How exactly would you sample? It is a tricky question and there are whole handbooks on how to do this properly. But let's assume that your sample is random and representative of the population. For example, if you picked random phone numbers from a phone book, you'll be missing people who don't have a phone; if you picked random people on the street, you'd be missing people from other parts of the country (e.g. from other cities, from rural areas); if you looked for them on church events you'd miss those who don't attend such events; if you picked random addresses you might miss the people who are currently in the hospitals (e.g. because of dementia!), etc. Another problem is that your sample size is rather small. You would be making claims regarding all the 65+ years old people in your country based on what you've learned from 100 people.

But let's say that everything is fine with the sampling. What you can say is that given this sample of 100 people you *estimated* the probability of dementia to be 0.1 with a 95% [confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) [0.04, 0.16]. You should also back this claim with a detailed description of the methodology used to come up with the estimate, so your readers can judge how reliable is the number.